# xcode - execution error with string

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, string, crash

I am trying to store and load some text from global variable in x-code. I declare it in main.m, outside of the main function. Then when I want to access it, I use extern. The application crashes after I click the saveButton second time with text in it. It seems like there would be some error rewriting the global labelString string. Can you figure this puzzle out please?

EDIT: Thanks to BKC, I have made some minor changes in the code, however I still get the same error. The code is updated.

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *field;

- (IBAction)saveButton:(id)sender;

FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString *labelString;
FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString *separator;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize field;

NSString *labelString = @"";
NSString *separator = @"|<->|";

- (IBAction)saveButton:(id)sender {
    if([field.text length] != 0) // if field isn't blank
    {
        if([labelString length] == 0) // nothing stored in labelString
        {
            labelString = field.text;
        }
        else // if something is already stored in labelString
        {
            NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", labelString, separator, field.text];
            labelString = str;
        }
        field.text = @"";
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [field release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please add a crash log.

Comment: In the log, the only thing is get is "(lldb)" I do however have a screenshot of the screen that comes up immediately when the app crashes. I dont quite know what it means though: http://i.imgur.com/0jrqB5n.png

Comment: @user2874028 Add an exception breakpoint in Xcode, that'll make your debugging easier: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html

Comment: The first time I click the button, everything works. It's the second time that it crashes. That's why I can't use breakpoints. It's because I cant set them to work after second time clicked.

Comment: Do you include main.m in your viewController?

Comment: No. When I tried doing #import "main.m" in my ViewController.m, it gave me this error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: @user2874028 That's the point of using an exception breakpoint. The debugger will stop as soon as an exception is raised, hopefully pointing to Objective C code and not assembly.

Comment: I did add the breakpoint as you suggested and it didn't do anything. It threw me back to the screen I posted screenshot of and nothing except lldb was written in console

Comment: I did try it few more times and I finally got something. I hope it helps: -[WebScriptObjectPrivate length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa987fc0

Comment: You are going about this in the weirdest way possible. What is it you are tying to do?

Comment: I want the user to be able to enter a string in a field and then press the saveButton. This will save the string in the labelString along with separator dividing other strings. Then, for each string in labelString a new label will be created in the app with the text of one string. I would do this with a for loop. It's not particularly useful, its just my project as this is how I test my abilities. I started with xcode - objective c like 4 days ago. Do you know understand what I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

The way you are defining the variable isn't right way. i use any global variable in my project something like this..
 **Declare the variable in .h file**

```
FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString *labelString; // Use extern if mixing with C++
```

**Define the varibale in .m file**

```
NSString *labelString = @"";
```

Include the header wherever you want to use that. i think in your code its crashing because of multiple time definition of labelString variable.

Comment: Thank you. Where exactly in the .m file am I supposed to define it? At the top or in the button IBAction?

Comment: you can define at the top

Comment: It compiled but after the second button click it has crashed again. I can't think of whats doing this.

Comment: did you removed any other declaration you are making in your viewController?

Comment: yep. Only thing I have in ViewController.h is the field, button and FOUNDATION_EXPORT of labelString and separator. I also went to ViewController.m and under @synthesize I added NSString labelString = @""; and NSString separator = @"|<->|";

Comment: FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString *labelString; and FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString *separator; should be above the interface.... and NSString *labelString = @""; and NSString *separator = @"|<->|"; also should be above the interface.. in their respective file.

Comment: That crashed immediately. *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<ViewController 0x75757f0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key infoLabel.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c90012 0x10cde7e 0x1d18fb1 0xb79e41 0xafb5f8 0xafb0e7 0xb25b58 0x22f019 0x10e1663 0x1c8b45a 0x22db1c 0xf27e7 0xf2dc8 0xf2ff8 0xf3232 0x423d5 0x4276f 0x42905 0x4b917 0xf96c 0x1094b 0x21cb5 0x22beb 0x14698 0x1bebdf9 0x1bebad0 0x1c05bf5 0x1c05962 0x1c36bb6 0x1c35f44 0x1c35e1b 0x1017a 0x11ffc 0x1d1a 0x1c35)

Comment: libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception